# Printing two different squares (made of asterisks) adjacent to each other?

Tags: python

I didn't know how to describe it in the question properly, so I'll try again here.

I have to solve this question where my code should print different types of squares. I have all of that figured out, however, I'm stuck at the printing part.

So, I start by inputting 4 as the size, and it results in different types of squares being made. For example, these two:

```
    first = ""
    for j in range(size-1):
        first += "*" * size + "\n"
    first += "*" * size

    two = ""
    for j in range(size-1):
        if j == 0:
            two += "*" * size + "\n"
        else:
            two += "*" + ((size - 2) * " ") + "*" + "\n"
    two += "*" * size
```

Now, I have to print them like this:

```
    ****  ****
    ****  *  *
    ****  *  *
    ****  ****
```

separated by a '\t'.

Since these squares are 'stored' in different strings, this is unfamiliar territory for me as the cursor is at the end of the first square. I don't know what to do, help pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways for that, one is here:

```
>>> v = '\n'.join([i+'\t' + j for i,j in list(zip([i for i in first.split('\n') if i], [ i for i in two.split('\n') if i]))])
>>> print(v)
****    ****
****    *  *
****    *  *
****    ****
```

What i did:

Splitted both strings at newline character, then took corresponding parts and joined them by tab in between, then assembled the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the data structure you use. Let the square will be not a string, but list of strings, where each string is line should be printed.

Then you can for each line write `line_first + '\t' + line_two` and print it.

This code worked as you expect.

```
first = []
for j in range(size - 1):
    first.append("*" * size)
first.append("*" * size)

two = []
for j in range(size - 1):
    if j == 0:
        two.append("*" * size)
    else:
        two.append("*" + ((size - 2) * " ") + "*")
two.append("*" * size)

for f, t in zip(first, two):
    print(f + '\t' + t)
```